# undo delete of gpg key

Tags: ssh, bug-reporting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using wsl on Windows 10 of Ubuntu:

1. I wanted to delete a GPG key (the GPG key of Microsoft), so I used the command "sudo apt-key list"
   [image of gpg keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38C5O.png) [Final of GPG Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOknn.png)
2. I write " sudo apt-key del BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF", and i can´t delete the GPG key.
   [Delete of GPG key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U50p.png)
3. I write " sudo apt-key del rsa2048 2015-10-28 [SC]" and appear an "ok"
   [Delete of GPG key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U50p.png)
4. I execute "sudo apt-key list" and then I see that Ubuntu delete a GPG of "ftpmaster@ubuntu.com"
   [Image of GPG deleted by mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZYhw.png) [Image of GPG deleted by mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3hv0.png)

So, I have two questions:

1. how I can add the gpg key of ubuntu that I delete by mistake?
2. Is this a bug on Ubuntu that I need to report? (ubuntu do not check the GPG key id correctly)

Offtopic: I execute "sudo apt-key del BE1229CF", so a deleted the GPG key that I wanted
[Delete the gpg key of Microsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxWQa.png) [Delete the GPG Key of Microsoft 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CBXY.png)